# Why does debugger say "class name = ..." instead of memory location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an object I'm initializing using some legacy method and things look weird in the debugger. Specifically, I see:

`(Foo *) class name = Foo`

instead of

`(Foo *) 0xWhatever`

The Foo object is created by an initializer which appears to be fine:

```
@implementation Foo

- (instancetype)initWithLegacyFoo:(LegacyFoo *)legacyFoo
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = legacyFoo.name;
        self.userId = legacyFoo.userId;
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Object appears to play nice though. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger calls the description method to print its log. I would check to see if that method was overridden in the offending class. 
e.g.

```
- (NSString *)description
{
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test class description"];
}
```

If I were to PO an instance of this class in the debugger, it would spit out "test class description" instead of a memory address